# Relational Database Question: Parent that references child

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Is it valid to have a parent table have a reference to a child table?

For example, a table Parents has a child table Children. Children has a foreign key Parent_ID linking back to its parent. But Parent has another column (say favorite_child_id) that is a foreign key back to the Child table. Is this acceptable or is it bad database design to have two tables essentially referencing each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not unusual and is a reasonable solution.  A common occurrence, for example, are contacts for a company.  One of the contacts might be designated the "primary contact".

The only issue is that you cannot declare both `favorite_child_id` to be n`NOT NULL` and `child.parent_id` to be `NOT NULL`.  If you do so, you are in a situation where you cannot add values into the table.

An alternative is to have an "is favorite" flag in the child table.  It can be tricky to ensure that *exactly* one child has that flag set.